# Solr 6.5.1 FL display not in order

Tags: solr, lucene

5.1 below solrconfig.xml

```
 <lst name="defaults">
  <str name="wt">json</str>
  <str name="indent">true</str>
  <str name="fl">name,id,CITY,countryCode</str>
  <str name="rows">50</str>
  <str name="df">Test_AC</str>
  <str name="sort">score desc</str>
</lst>
<arr name="components">
  <str>query</str>
</arr>
```

But in output i am not getting proper order

actual
{
name: "Test 1",
city: "city_test",
id: "23456",
countryCode:US
}

expected display order in fl

{
name: "Test 1",
id: "23456",
city: "city_test",
countryCode:US
}

I am using solr for searching and lucene to index creation

Answer (score 0):

Field order is not guaranteed. Neither from Solr or in a JSON object, and would also depend on the language you're querying from (i.e. the dictionary object returned from your solr library / JSON library may not guarantee order).

If you need order, keep a separate list of the the order you want to return elements in, and iterate over that list when displaying fields.

```
field_order = ['name', 'id', 'city', 'countryCode']

for doc in documents:
    for field in field_order:
        print(doc[field])
```

Comment: can we right any custom respons so that we can reorder fileds dispaly. I am using java language. Solr 6.5.1 for searching and lucene for indexing 6.5.1

Comment: I'm not sure if the output format used by SolrJ (if that's what you're using) which uses javabin has inherent order support in the type it exports. It's probably a lot easier and easier to maintain by creating a support class in your code base.